# Why don't glyphicons work as anchors?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

Having a problem with my large project for my company. On my procedure pages I have standard anchor tags. I have them set to open a new window and pop up a thumbnail if you hover over them. Works great. However I tried adding a glyphicon right after the anchor trigger work to handle the pop up function and no go. Here is working snippet of html-

```
<a href="images/Nibrotom/IMG_0200.jpg" target="_blank">cover </a>
```

Now add a glyphicon...still looks fine

```
<a href="images/Nibrotom/IMG_0200.jpg" target="_blank">cover </a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
```

now wrap the glyph in my pop up code (I do it with CSS) and its broke.

```
<a href="images/Nibrotom/IMG_0200.jpg" target="_blank">cover </a>
<a href="#" class="thumb" onClick="return false;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"><img src="images/Nibrotom/IMG_0200.jpg"></span></a>
```

any ideas on why this doesn't work? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your span wrapping the glyphicon is wrapping your image too.

Change your anchor tags from this:

```
<a href="images/Nibrotom/IMG_0200.jpg" target="_blank">
    cover
</a>
<a href="#" class="thumb" onClick="return false;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"><img src="images/Nibrotom/IMG_0200.jpg">
    </span>
</a>
```

To this:

```
<a href="images/Nibrotom/IMG_0200.jpg" target="_blank">
    cover
</a>
<a href="#" class="thumb" onClick="return false;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> <img src="images/Nibrotom/IMG_0200.jpg">
</a>
```

Comment: The change you made is outside the viewport of the code block? Can you indent your code so its easier to read and also add an explanation of why this works?

Comment: Already tried it that way @Andrew. If I copy and paste your code what happens is the thumbnail is displayed in the paragraph. To hide it until I hover the IMG link has to go into within the "span" element Here is working code from the same page to illustrate what I'm talking about:            <a href="#" class="thumb" onClick="return false;">Gimme five <span class="left1"><img src="images/gimme-five.gif"></span></a>

Comment: Sorry was trying to get my code to display right and I ran into the 5 minute limit to edit comment. I honestly think its a glitch in Bootstrap's code. Once you put anything within the glyph's span tag it breaks it. Heck I even tried putting another span tag right after the glyph span tag within the anchor and that doesn't work either. For things like this I'm gonna have to use JQuery and re-do the code.